# django 1.6 tutorial3 "current url doesn't match any pattern"

Tags: django-views, django-urls, django-1.6

Python 2.7.3

I am new in django and I am following the tutorial at :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/

I followed exactly the steps described:

Here is a copy/paste from files in the project:

**cat polls/views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
        return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")
```

from /mysite: **cat urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)'),
)
```

**cat polls/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

The page debug shows the following error:
[image]

It looks like, **it doesn't recognize the "polls" pattern in /mysite/urls.py.**

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at

`url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')'),`

Change it to: (From the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/)

`url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),`